# Does Elixir have a variable which holds the name of the current file (ala Ruby’s __FILE__)?

Tags: elixir

How in Elixir can I specify the current file being compiled? In Ruby, I can use the `__FILE__` variable. Is there an equivalent in Elixir?

Here is my script:

```
IO.puts “#{__FILE__}”
```

Here is the output:

```
** (CompileError) ModulesAndFunctions-7.exs:3: undefined function __FILE__/0
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.to_string/1
    ModulesAndFunctions-7.exs:3: (file)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use [__ENV__.file](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#__ENV__/0)

Comment: Can you update your answer to :`__ENV__.file` please?